# Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt; this is the error. I do not know how to get the row in jsp?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

**when i hit my url i getting an exception it is saying Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>**

> http://localhost:8081/Spring_hibernate/search?keyword=core

**this is dao part**

```
public Offer getSearchByName(String companyName) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query<Offer> query = session.createNamedQuery("findBy.app", Offer.class);
        query.setParameter("offerDetails", companyName);
        Offer offerResult = query.getSingleResult();
        return offerResult;
    }
```

**this is the controller**

> ```
> @RequestMapping("/search")
>  public String search(@RequestParam("keyword") String offerDetails , Model model) {
>     Offer offer = offerDaoImpl.getSearchByName(offerDetails);
>     System.out.println("from search method "+offer.toString());
>     model.addAttribute("searchObject", offer);
>    return "search";
>    }
> ```

**this the jsp page**

```
<c:forEach var="temp" items="${searchObject}">
       <tr>
        <td>${temp.id}</td>
        <td>${temp.companayName}</td>
        <td>${temp.offerDetails}</td>
        <td>${temp.price}</td>
        <td><a href="/Spring_hibernate/deleteOffer?offerId=${temp.id}">Delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="/Spring_hibernate/updateOffer?offerId=${temp.id}">Update</a></td>
       </tr>
   </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only iterate valid Object array such as Collection, Map, Iterator, Enumeration or String. Anything else can't be iterated by <c:forEach>.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show a list. Get your query result in a collection, set that collection in "searchObject".

If the query result is not a collection, then remove forEach iterator and simply access the fields (searchObject.price).

Comment: thank you , I got it . I changed in my dao as a list ...